# How to use WinAppDbg to hook and call existing functions given RVA of that function?

Tags: python, debugging, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to use WinAppDbg to write plugins for a game, which involves hooking and calling existing functions in that game. After some reverse engineering work, I got the RVAs and signatures of some target functions or class methods. But soon I found that the document of WinAppDbg only tells me how to hook existing functions rather than to call them. Furthermore, normally the address of a target function is got from Process.resolve_label, but I only have RVAs. How can I hook a function with its RVA? Thanks!

------------------ Update 1-----------------------

In order to make it clear what I'm trying to do, consider the following case:

There is a class method called `bool Player::attack(this, Animal *some_animal)` in `some_game.exe`, which will be called when I attack any animal. I want to monitor the attack event and perhaps simulate/trigger an attack event whenever I want.

After examining the 'some_game.pdb' file, I figured out that the RVA of the target function, i.e. `Player::attack`, is `0x00678840`. And I made a `myplugin.dll` file which will be injected in the game process.

Then it's quite simple to call this function in `myplugin.dll` like this

```cpp
#include <windows.h>

auto module_addr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>(GetModuleHandle(NULL));
attack_func = reinterpret_cast<void(*)(void*, void*)>(0x00678840+module_addr);
attack_func(...)
```

And hooking is also quite easy with the help of the [Microsoft Detours library](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours) by first defining a helper hook function `void RegisterStaticHook(RVA sym, void* hook, void** org);`:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
// Detours
#include <detours/detours.h>

typedef uint64_t VA;
typedef unsigned int RVA;

template<typename Type>
using Ptr = Type*;

enum class HookErrorCode {
    ERR_SUCCESS,
    ERR_TRANSACTION_BEGIN,
    ERR_UPDATE_THREAD,
    ERR_ATTACH,
    ERR_DETACH,
    ERR_TRANSACTION_COMMIT
};
template<typename T = Ptr<void>>
auto Hook(Ptr<T> p, T f) {
    int error = DetourTransactionBegin();
    if (error != NO_ERROR) {
        return HookErrorCode::ERR_TRANSACTION_BEGIN;
    }
    error = DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
    if (error != NO_ERROR) {
        return HookErrorCode::ERR_UPDATE_THREAD;
    }
    error = DetourAttach(
        reinterpret_cast<Ptr<PVOID>>(p),
        reinterpret_cast<PVOID>(f)
    );
    if (error != NO_ERROR) {
        return HookErrorCode::ERR_ATTACH;
    }
    error = DetourTransactionCommit();
    if (error != NO_ERROR) {
        return HookErrorCode::ERR_TRANSACTION_COMMIT;
    }
    return HookErrorCode::ERR_SUCCESS;
}

void RegisterStaticHook(RVA sym, void* hook, void** org) {
    auto base = reinterpret_cast<VA>(GetModuleHandle(NULL));
    *org = reinterpret_cast<void*>(base + sym);
    auto ret = Hook<void*>(org, hook);
    if (ret != HookErrorCode::ERR_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "[Error] ";
        switch (ret) {
        case HookErrorCode::ERR_TRANSACTION_BEGIN:
            std::cout << "DetourTransactionBegin";
            break;
        case HookErrorCode::ERR_UPDATE_THREAD:
            std::cout << "DetourUpdateThread";
            break;
        case HookErrorCode::ERR_ATTACH:
            std::cout << "DetourAttach";
            break;
        case HookErrorCode::ERR_DETACH:
            std::cout << "DetourDetach";
            break;
        case HookErrorCode::ERR_TRANSACTION_COMMIT:
            std::cout << "DetourTransactionCommit";
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        std::cout << "failed!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Then hook `my_attack` with 'RegisterStaticHook' like this:

```cpp
void** org;
bool my_attack(void* player_this, void* animal){
...
}

RegisterStaticHook(0x00678840, my_attack, org);
```

My question is how to do it with WinAppDbg.

Comment: What have you tried this far. Give us some code and a specific error message or description how your not work.

Comment: Actually I even don't know how to do it yet, so I cannot try anything. I've succeeded in doing it in C++, and I know how to do it with [Microsoft's Detour library](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours). However, since I only know a little about the underlying things, and WinAppDbg doesn't give me any related examples, I just don't know how to do it from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: WinAppDbg doesn't really support this, and it would be kinda difficult to do so. Try Microsoft Detours instead.

Long explanation:

WinAppDbg is a debugger, which means the target program you want to patch/hook etc. is running in a separate Windows process than your Python script. It can only interact with the debugged process in ways allowed by the Win32 API, and unfortunately there is no mechanism for executing functions in the target process.

You could, with some work, emulate this functionality somewhat. Basically it would mean to modify the registers and stack to execute the beginning of the hooked function, make sure all pointers in the stack actually point to valid memory in the process, and possibly allocate some trampoline code to allow WinAppDbg to break execution once the function has returned. This would have to be done all over again for both 32 and 64 bits due to architecture differences. This is basically what debuggers like GDB do.

On the other hand, Detours works by injecting a DLL directly into the memory of the process you want to target - so executing code there is a breeze, since you don't have to deal with weird Win32 API calls or map memory across processes. It's also a hell of a lot faster. But you will have to code in C instead of Python.